# EF 6 .Database.SqlQuery for Stored proc just returns string of stored proc

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

The results returned is just the string passed to SQLQuery...

```
             var beginDt = new DateTime(2014, 03, 17);
                string beginDtStr = beginDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                var callParams = new object[]
                {
                    dbName
                    , true
                    , 4
                    , 5 //   @EntityAffiliateTypeID 
                    , "Test Name "
                    , "Empty Note" /
                    , "5192223333"
                    , "5193334444"
                    , "bing@bing.com"
                    , "59 London Rd"
                    , null
                    , 8
                    , "Sarnia"
                    , 53
                    , "N7T2B1"
                    , 6
                    , 2
                    , null
                    , null
                    , null
                    , beginDtStr
                    , null
                    , "Another Testname"
                    , "5192223333"
                    , "5193334444"
                    , "email@domain.com"
                    , null
                    , null
                };

              var result2 = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
                    "EXEC SPEntityAffiliateInsert {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}",
                    callParams
                    );
```

When you examine result2, it's just exactly:

```
"EXEC SPEntityAffiliateInsert {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}"
```

it's like you make the select statement for a string:

```
SELECT 'EXEC SPEntityAffiliateInsert {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}';
```

So, how do I get it to actually invoke the sproc?

(I already tried:
                  var result2 = db.Database.SqlQuery(
                        "SPEntityAffiliateInsert {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}",

and
                  var result2 = db.Database.SqlQuery(
                        "EXEC SPEntityAffiliateInsert {0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} {11} {12} {13} {14} {15} {16} {17} {18} {19} {20} {21} {22} {23} {24} {25} {26} {27}",
)
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues here was that the regular method of calling an SP won't work; this SP uses the Return statement for a single integer value. All normal EF SP calling conventions expect an IEnumerable compatible result, So I had to act differently - I was not allowed to update the SP.

The string wasn't being interpreted as a command as the SP was not qualified by a schema. I also updated it to run exactly as it would be run in a Query window:

```
var commandSQL = "DECLARE @return_value int; " +
      "EXEC @return_value = [dbSchemaName].[SPEntityAffiliateInsert] " +
       "@ParamXName = {0} ; SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value;";
```

Tthen call it:

```
   IEnumerable<int> results = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(commandSQL, strParams.ToArray()).ToList();
                    foreach (int result in results)
                    {
                        model.expectedresultsfromDBfield = result;
                        //only looking for one result...(could have called FirstOrDefault, I suppose...
                        break;
                    }
```

All works fine